# Working with Mercurial locally and SVN remotely?

Tags: windows, svn, mercurial

At work we use Subversion, but because nobody understands how to branch our "branching" involves copying the entire codebase and treating it as a separate repository - this means any changes we do to the "patch" branch need to be copied/pasted to the main development ("trunk") branch so they are in sync and we cannot use any built-in merging tools (We manually using WinMerge or similar to find the lines that changed).  Nobody wants to take the time out to learn how to use SVN's branching capabilities and instead encourage using this strategy as an alternative.

Since I cannot convince everyone else to look into real branching, I'm looking at doing something for myself to make the merges less painful.  I have wanted to look into Mercurial for a while now (I have previously used Git a little on my Mac; Windows7 at work) as a wholesale SVN replacement if I could get buy-in.

My question is this:  First, would it be difficult to use Mercurial on my local machine if I would have to push changes out to two SVN repositories?  Locally I could use branching to merge the code back in easily, keeping the SVN repos different would be a simple matter of pushing the branch to the patch code, and the dev branch (after merging of course) to the dev branch in SVN, right?

Second, before I introduce Mercurial is there a better way of doing this?  I've tried to tell my co-workers about using SVN's branching but the answer I get is that "this works for now" as nobody wants to take the time to learn SVN branching, and to be 100% honest I have never used SVN branching myself so I'm not sure how easy/hard it is to use, and don't want to risk trying to branch and messing something up.

Comment: I thought that copying (albeit "cheap" copying) was the standard way to do branching in SVN anyway. Note that I'm not a big SVN user, but that's how branching is done on some of the projects at my workplace, and how the svn book defines it.

Comment: Maybe, we aren't using SVN's branches I mean we're actually copying the files (basically doing an SVN Export to get all the files, and renaming the folder, then recommitting it to SVN and treating it as a totally different repository).

Comment: @WayneM Do you act on the same, or a different svn repo?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure; looking at the Repo Browser I see a "main" folder with let's say two folders under it: Development and Patch.  We commit bug fixes *only* to Patch, and then have to manually copy the changes to Development.

Comment: If **one window** but **two sources** you can merge pathes inside SVN, I suppose

Comment: There is a problem here, and that is that you're not using the tools as they are intended. If you have decided that you're not going to learn branching properly, Mercurial, Git, Subversion, TFS, Vault, basically *any* version control system is going to fight you. You ask if there is a better way of doing this, and yes, it is, you learn how to use the tool properly. The problem with manual merging with a merge tool is that you need to know exactly what changed, or you risk copying changes the wrong way (ie. you interpret a delete in branch A as an insert in branch B instead.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to be honest if you’re getting this kind of response about the most basic things of SVN branching, do you really think you could convince them to switch their entire repository system?

For sure though, “don’t want to risk trying to branch and messing something up” is very typical of SVN, and something that Mercurial does a lot better; as you are always working in a local repository, experimenting and making mistakes is cheap and you can just make a new clone if you mess up. I would definitely recommend Mercurial over SVN in pretty much any situation except for repositories that must hold large amounts of binary data such as art repositories.

Now as for your questions,

In principle, you can use the same working directory for a Mercurial repository and an SVN repository. You probably want to add .hg and .svn to SVN and Mercurial’s ignore filters, and of course changes you commit to Mercurial don’t automatically commit to SVN. However it can be convenient to use Mercurial as a scratchpad for local development. If you have two SVN checkouts you want to do this in, you can indeed just exchange data between Mercurial clones by pulling or pushing from the one to the other.

To be honest though, in response to your second question, I think the ‘better way’ is just to learn SVN’s branching and merge mechanics. Running Mercurial on top of SVN can be pretty cumbersome, and may be more trouble than it’s worth. If you want to experiment with SVN merging, you could make a test SVN repository to practice branching and merging there.

If your coworkers have decided on SVN and can’t be bothered about Mercurial, you probably just have to live with it. Maybe there is some consolation in the fact that there are many in similar situations, I’d personally love to stop using SVN sooner rather than later, but still in my previous and current company I’m unfortunately stuck with it. Although at my current company, they’re open to changing it at some point in the future and we’re already working with git for an external project.

One more thing I should probably mention: there are tools like the hgsubversion extension that allow you to work with Mercurial on top of SVN, converting all commits into Mercurial commits. I would not really recommend that though, especially if you’re a novice Mercurial user, the fundamental mismatch between SVN and Mercurial means that branching isn’t really possible if you want to push your changes back, you have to rebase all the time and you can very easily end up with data loss.

Comment: Merge changesets **will be** pushed to SVN without problem. Multiply heads in branch will be headache, yes, but working repo will have always  only code commits and merge commits

Answer (score 1):

Note:

```
svn merge URL1 URL2
```

can be used even for **unrelated** URLs (*different repos*). Merge inside one repo is just a convention and workflow

> would it be difficult to use Mercurial on my local machine if I would have to push changes out to two SVN repositories?

No, always is transparent

- Repo1 for MainSVN pull MainSVN + pull Repo2 + merge heads +push
- MainSVN Repo2 for DevSVN (pull DevSVN + push DevSVN)

> before I introduce Mercurial is there a better way of doing this?

See my starting note - you can at least **try** native svn  merge between repos